# Read PDF/ Excel using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

How to read content in PDF/Excel using robot framework?

I tried below code to read Excel
Open Workbook     ${EXECDIR}/Data/Documents/Gxp.xlsx
Sleep    5s
$ {column1} = Get cell value 1 2

I got this error
**No Workbook is active**

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

did you install liblary RPA Framework ??
if you didnt install you can go to this [site](https://rpaframework.org/#installation)

this example code to see this code or you can visit the [website](https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/pdf/how-to-read-pdf-files)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Read the text contained in PDF files and save it to a
...                 corresponding text file.
Library             RPA.PDF
Library             RPA.FileSystem
*** Tasks ***
Extract text from PDF files
Extract text from PDF file into a text file    simple-text-example.pdf
Extract text from PDF file into a text file    example-invoice.pdf
*** Keywords **
Extract text from PDF file into a text file
[Arguments]    ${pdf_file_name}
${text}=    Get Text From Pdf    ${pdf_file_name}
 Create File    ${OUTPUT_DIR}${/}${pdf_file_name}.txt
 FOR    ${page}    IN    @{text.keys()}
Append To File
...    ${OUTPUT_DIR}${/}${pdf_file_name}.txt
 ...    ${text[${page}]}
END
```